# Java permutations

Tags: java

I am trying to run my code so it prints cyclic permutations, though I can only get it to do the first one at the moment. It runs correctly up to the point which I have marked but I can't see what is going wrong. I think it has no break in the while loop, but I'm not sure. Really could do with some help here.

```
package permutation;

public class Permutation {
static int DEFAULT = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = DEFAULT;
    if (args.length > 0)
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    int[] OA = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        OA[i] = i + 1;

    System.out.println("The original array is:");
    for (int i = 0; i < OA.length; i++)
        System.out.print(OA[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("A permutation of the original array is:");
    OA = generateRandomPermutation(n);
    printArray(OA);
    printPemutation(OA);
}

static int[] generateRandomPermutation(int n)// (a)
{
    int[] A = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = i + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * (n));
        int swap = A[r];
        A[r] = A[i];
        A[i] = swap;
    }
    return A;
}

static void printArray(int A[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

static void printPemutation(int p[])// (b)
{
    System.out
            .println("The permutation is represented by the cyclic notation:");
    int[] B = new int[p.length];
    int m = 0;
    while (m < p.length)// this is the point at which my code screws up
    {
        if (!check(B, m)) {
            B = parenthesis(p, m);
            printParenthesis(B);
            m++;
        } else
            m++;
    }// if not there are then repeat
}

static int[] parenthesis(int p[], int i) {
    int[] B = new int[p.length];
    for (int a = p[i], j = 0; a != B[0]; a = p[a - 1], j++) {
        B[j] = a;
    }
    return B;
}

static void printParenthesis(int B[]) {
    System.out.print("( ");
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length && B[i] != 0; i++)
        System.out.print(B[i] + " ");
    System.out.print(")");
}

static boolean check(int B[], int m) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean a = false;
    while (i < B.length || !a) {
        if ((ispresent(m, B, i))){
            a = true;
            break;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return a;
}

static boolean ispresent(int m, int B[], int i) {
    return m == B[i] && m < B.length;
}
}
```

Comment: Do us all a favour and run your code through an automatic indenter. You have nested ifs and such at the exact same level of indentation, which makes it unnecessarily difficult to decipher the logic.

Comment: homework, please tag as such.

Comment: homework is a meta tag and thus discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among others you should check p[m] in check(B, p[m]) instead of m:

in static void printPemutation(int p[]):

```
while (m < p.length){
    if (!check(B, p[m])) {
         B = parenthesis(p, m);
         printParenthesis(B);
    }
    m++;
}
```

then

```
static boolean check(int B[], int m) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < B.length) {
        if (m == B[i]) {
            return true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this does somehow more what you want, but not always i fear...

Comment: I just want it to shift to the next cyclic permutation say for 51432 represented as (521)(43). At the moment however it is only printing (521). The check method runs through (521) and sees what the first number not in it is and then starts printing the second bracket, or that is the idea anyway. However I'm at a dead end with ideas on how to get it to shift to start printing the next bracket.

Comment: Implementing you tip I now get

Comment: The original array is:
1 2 3 4 
A permutation of the original array is:
2 3 1 4 
The permutation is represented by the cyclic notation:
( 2 3 1 )( 2 3 1 )( 3 1 2 )( 1 2 3 )( 4 )

Comment: Sorry, I can not fully fix your code. I think you have some errors in the permutation function too. Maybe you should first try to create valid permutations for one class: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation e.g. (1 2),(1 3),(1 4),(2 3),(2 4),(3 4)

Comment: Trying to debug It seems to think the error is in the third from last line. In the ispresent method. Any other ideas for how to scan the printed cycle to find the next step or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think your parenthesis(int p[], int i) method is the first problem, it does not create correct cycles. And then it does not make sense to loop over p.length (m). You expect 6 groups but with looping over p.length you will only get 4.

Comment: I have to correct myself, you expect 24 elements, as described on the wikipedia article I posted before. But its late here now... good luck!

Comment: Say for the 2314 example my perfect solution would be to print (231)(4) as in the group theory examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation. At most you would expect 4 groups say for 1234 (1)(2)(3)(4), I think the parenthesis is right just not sure about how to get it to jump from B[0] to B[3] (B[3]=4 is the next one not already included in the cycles). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks. Its almost there so hopefully I can get the last bit now. Thanks for all the help.