# Java permutations 2

Tags: java

I asked a question on helping me with this question about a week ago

### [Java permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340897/java-permutations)

, with a problem in the print permutation method. I have tidied up my code and have a working example that now works although if 5 is in the 5th position in the array it doesn't print it. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
 package permutation;

public class Permutation {

static int DEFAULT = 100;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = DEFAULT;
    if (args.length > 0)
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] OA = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        OA[i] = i + 1;
    System.out.println("The original array is:");
    for (int i = 0; i < OA.length; i++)
        System.out.print(OA[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("A permutation of the original array is:");
    OA = generateRandomPermutation(n);
    printArray(OA);
    printPermutation(OA);
}

static int[] generateRandomPermutation(int n)// (a)
{
    int[] A = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = i + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * (n));
        int swap = A[r];
        A[r] = A[i];
        A[i] = swap;
    }
    return A;
}

static void printArray(int A[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        System.out.print(A[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

static void printPermutation(int[] p)

{
    int n = p.length-1;
    int j = 0;
    int m;
    int f = 0;

    System.out.print("(");
    while (f < n) {
        m = p[j];
        if (m == 0) {
            do
                f++;
            while (p[f] == 0 && f < n);
            j = f;
            if (f != n)
                System.out.print(")(");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.print(" " + m);
            p[j] = 0;
            j = m - 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" )");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too crazy about

```
int n = p.length-1;
```

followed by

```
while (f < n) {
```

So if p is 5 units long, and f starts at 0, then the loop will be from 0 to 3. That would seem to exclude the last element in the array.

Comment: If I change it to int n = p.length it gives back an error though. This is my problem, that it doesn't read until the last element, and though trying to follow where the error is I can't find it.

Comment: Fair enough.  Have you stepped through the routine with a debugger to see where things go awry?  What error is being given?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at permutation.Permutation.printPermutation(Permutation.java:58)
 at permutation.Permutation.main(Permutation.java:21)

Comment: So its basically running out of the length of the array. Though in that case it does print the 5 if its in the 5th position though not the last bracket, changing the length gets rid of the error but also the last number.

Comment: Why don't you just print the permutation the same way you print the original array? The permutation is being held in the exact same sort of array.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I think I because I have to write it represented in cycles.

Comment: Look at this line - it could be where your error is happening.  _while (p[f] == 0 && f < n);_  The exception is likely happening at p[f].  The check to protect you f<n happens 2nd in the conditional. Swap their orders and report back.

Comment: Think it's fixed it. What was your reasoning for the switch for future reference?

Comment: Good question. Java conditionals are evaluated left-to-right.  This means that your array lookup happened before the check to make sure the index was in bounds.  Thus, when your index went out of bounds the array lookup threw the exception.  When the checks are reversed, however, the boounds checks happens first, and _because the rest of the conditional statement is meaningless_ the array lookup code is skipped when the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks. You've been a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shuffle method of the Collections class

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<Integer> arrList = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.shuffle(arrList);
System.out.println(arrList);
```

Comment: Its homework and I have to use imperative(?) methods although though that would be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think swapping each element with a random other element will give a uniform distribution of permutations.  Better to select uniformly from the remaining values:

```
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> remainingValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    remainingValues.add(i);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int next = rand.nextInt(remainingValues.size());
    result[i] = remainingValues.remove(next);
}
```

Note that if order of running-time is a concern, using an ArrayList in this capacity is n-squared time.  There are data-structures which could handle this task in n log n time but they are very non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the problem you have identified.

Rather i think it identifies a mistake with  your  generateRandomPermutation(int n) proc.

If you add a print out of the random numbers generated (as i did below) and run the proc a few times it allows us to check if all the elements in the ARRAY TO BE permed are being randomly selected.

```
static int[] generateRandomPermutation(int n)
{
    int[] A = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = i + 1;
     System.out.println("random nums generated are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * (n));
         System.out.print(r + " ");
```

Run the proc several times. 
Do you see what i see?

Jerry.